# Create and Fill Duplicate Dataframe Values with Lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find a way to arrange a dataframe given a path that leads to several numbers that are read from files in that path.

I have a dataframe that has a JobID and the path associated with that job that looks as follows:

```
JobID       Path

43402866    /global/162940/mill/scanfiles0001   

43408681    /global/162940/mill/scanfiles0002
```

When I change directories to the paths from the job I read values and get results that look something like the following lists:

```
/global/162940/mill/scanfiles0001
[256, 10.0, 2605, 100, 86000]
[256, 20.0, 5210, 100, 86000]
[256, 40.0, 10421, 100, 86000]
[256, 50.0, 13026, 100, 86000]

/global/162940/mill/scanfiles0002
[256, 60.0, 15631, 100, 86000]
[256, 80.0, 20841, 100, 86000]
[256, 120.0, 31262, 100, 86000]
```

I wanted to ask if there's a way to get the data in the following form

```
JobID      Path           A    B     C     D    E

43402866   /global/...1   256  10.0  2605  100  86000
43402866   NaN            256  20.0  5210  100  86000
43402866   NaN            256  40.0  10421 100  86000
43402866   NaN            256  50.0  13026 100  86000

43408681   /global/...2   256  60.0  15631 100  86000
43408681   NaN            256  80.0  20841 100  86000
43408681   NaN            256  120.0 31262 100  86000
```

Where jobIDs are duplicated for all the different lists and repeated paths are omitted or turned into NaNs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this:

```py
# Initial dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "JobID": ["43402866", "43408681"],
        "Path": [
            "/global/162940/mill/scanfiles0001",
            "/global/162940/mill/scanfiles0002",
        ],
    }
)

# Initialize Target dataframe
new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"JobID": [], "Path": [], "A": [], "B": [], "C": [], "D": [], "E": []}
)

# Fake data for the purpose of the demonstration
scanfiles0001 = [
    [256, 10.0, 2605, 100, 86000],
    [256, 20.0, 5210, 100, 86000],
    [256, 40.0, 10421, 100, 86000],
    [256, 50.0, 13026, 100, 86000],
]

# Fake data for the purpose of the demonstration
scanfiles0002 = [
    [256, 60.0, 15631, 100, 86000],
    [256, 80.0, 20841, 100, 86000],
    [256, 120.0, 31262, 100, 86000],
]

# Fake data for the purpose of the demonstration
scanfiles = {
    "/global/162940/mill/scanfiles0001": scanfiles0001,
    "/global/162940/mill/scanfiles0002": scanfiles0002,
}

start = 0
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    for line in scanfiles[row["Path"]]:
        new_df.loc[len(new_df), ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]] = line
    new_df["JobID"].fillna(row["JobID"], inplace=True)
    new_df.loc[start, "Path"] = row["Path"]
    start += len(new_df)

print(new_df)
# Outputs
      JobID                               Path      A      B        C      D        E
0  43402866  /global/162940/mill/scanfiles0001  256.0   10.0   2605.0  100.0  86000.0
1  43402866                                NaN  256.0   20.0   5210.0  100.0  86000.0
2  43402866                                NaN  256.0   40.0  10421.0  100.0  86000.0
3  43402866                                NaN  256.0   50.0  13026.0  100.0  86000.0
4  43408681  /global/162940/mill/scanfiles0002  256.0   60.0  15631.0  100.0  86000.0
5  43408681                                NaN  256.0   80.0  20841.0  100.0  86000.0
6  43408681                                NaN  256.0  120.0  31262.0  100.0  86000.0
```